# How can I add the following JSON to a new URL based on its "category": 2?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a JSON array in my server in Django rest framework, but I want to filter them by `category` , for example some of them have `'category':1` and some of them have `'category':2` like this:

```
[
            {
                "id": 667,
                "image": "https://ae0g",
                "description": "GRE",
                "price": "USD .11",
                "buy": "https://sn",
                "category": 1
            },
            {
                
                "image": "https://ae04.",
                "description": "10/13 ",
                "price": ".18",
                "buy": "https://",
                "category": 2
            }
]
```

How can I add the following JSON to a new URL based on its `"category": 2`?

```
            "image": "https://ae04.",
            "description": "10/13 ",
            "price": ".18",
            "buy": "https://",
            "category": 2
```

views:

```
class productviewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset=product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = productSerializer 
    pagination_class = None

    def create(self, request):
        serialized = productSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        if serialized.is_valid():
            serialized.save()
            return Response(serialized.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serialized._errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    @action (detail=False , methods=['post']) 
    def delete(self,request):
        product.objects.all().delete()
        return Response('success')
```

urls:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'product', productviewset,basename='product')
 

# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this thingy you call "json array" is set of database objects you can apply filter as described in [drf docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters). So in your case it would require to override `get_queryset` method of `ModelViewSet` class.

```py
class productviewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset=product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = productSerializer 
    pagination_class = None

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Optionally restricts the returned product to a given category,
        by filtering against a `category` query parameter in the URL.
        """
        queryset = product.objects.all()
        category = self.request.query_params.get('category')
        if category is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(category=category)
        return queryset

    def create(self, request):
        serialized = productSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        if serialized.is_valid():
            serialized.save()
            return Response(serialized.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serialized._errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    @action (detail=False , methods=['post']) 
    def delete(self,request):
        product.objects.all().delete()
        return Response('success')
```

Then, if you hit `/product?category=2` it should be filtered. Also, you might want to use `django-filters` package, but that's overkill in your case.

Also when you code in Django (or python in general), remember to capitalize every class name so `productviewset` should be `ProductViewSet` and so on. I highly encourage to read DRF source code, which is well written and explains a lot of things.